# Collapsing and averaging redundant entries in MATLAB table

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB table

```
item_a item_b score
a      b      1
a      b      1
b      c      3
d      e      2
d      e      1
d      e      0
```

I want to average the redundant rows. The desired result is as follows:

```
item_a item_b score
a      b      (1+1)/2
b      c      3
d      e      (2+1+0)/3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got. You can tweak with the final results. There is a similar example on MATLAB documentation. Here are two key functions, `accumarray` and `unique`. Note that this solution works only for array inputs not cell data types. By manipulating data types, you can also find the solution for table and cell data types. Otherwise, I think for loop will be necessary.

```
items = ['a'      'b'   
    'a'      'b'    
    'b'      'c'    
    'd'      'e'      
    'd'      'e'   
    'd'      'e' ];
scores = [1 1 3 2 1 0]';
[items_unique,ia,ic] = unique(items,'rows');
score_mean = accumarray(ic,scores, [], @mean);
result = {items_unique score_mean};
```

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to your answer because you addressed the unique rows issue. I cross-posted to mathworks and I got the following optimal answer `G = groupsummary(t,[1 2],'mean');
`

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic scenario for the findgroups, split-apply workflow.
Given your table named `t`:

```
% Find mean values.
G = findgroups(t.item_a);
meanValues = splitapply(@mean,t.score,G);

% Create new table.
[~,i] = unique(G);
newTable = t(i,:);
newTable.score = meanValues
```

`newTable` contains the desired table.

---

See [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/grouping-variables-for-splitting-data.html) documentation page for more examples.